Failed to import external .js file
I am newbie on Framework7-Core (bundler vite) and I tried to import an external javascript (test.js) into app.f7. When I sync & build the package, it shows as below.
[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import “/src/js/test.js” from “D:/Project/MobileScreenTest/src/app.f7”.
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
Anybody may help me how to load the external javascript file?
Software version

OpenJDK 17.0.9
Node v21.7.3
Npm 10.8.1
Framework7 8.3.3
Capacitor/android 6.1.0
Capacitor/app 6.0.0
Capacitor/cli 6.1.0
Capacitor/core 6.1.0

Exmaples:
app.f7
<template>
  <div id="app">

    <!-- Your main view, should have "view-main" class -->
    <div class="view view-main view-init safe-areas" data-url="/"></div>

    <!-- Popup -->
    <div class="popup popup-tablet-fullscreen" id="my-popup">
      <div class="page">
        <div class="page-content" style="width:100%"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import test from '/src/js/test.js';

  export default (props, { $f7, $on, $update }) => {
    $on('pageInit', () => {
      console.log(test.result);
    });
    return $render;
  }
</script>

test.js
const result = 'Hello';
export default result;

